# Convert out.println to c:out

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

What is the `JSTL` `c:out` version of this `JSP`:

```
<% 

 PersonController personController = new PersonController();
 personController.populate();
 out.println(personController.getAllPeople().get(0).getName()); 

%>
```

**The code running behind this:**

In `PersonController`:

```
List<Person> allPeople = new ArrayList<Person>();

public void populate() {
  Person person = new Person();
  person.setName("Jeff");
  allPeople.add(person);
}

public List<Person> getAllPeople() {
    return allPeople;
}

public void setAllPeople(List<Person> allPeople) {
    this.allPeople = allPeople;
}
```

In `Person`:

```
private String name;

public String getName() {
   return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
```

Comment: where do you add an instance of `PersonController` as an attribute on the request??

Comment: See the `populate()` method in the Controller

Comment: That won't cut it. You need to place it on the `request` using `request.setAttribute()` or create the bean with a `JSP` tag.  If you are creating an instance of `PersonController` on the JSP please post that code.  Somewhere somehow an instance of `PersonController` must be bound to the request or session.

Comment: Without knowing how/where/what you're doing before the view layer it's a bit more difficult to answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following Expression which works:

```
<c:out value="${personController.allPeople[0].name }"/>
```

If the following expression does not work you have other issues within your code.  I suspect that an instance of `personController` is never being bound to the request using `setAttribute()` or via a JSP tag.  At somepoint in the code an instance of `personController` must be placed within the request or session so that it may be referenced by the JSP EL.

---

### Using a Servlet

I have constructed a [GitHub Gist](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/8439836) which may provide some insights.  Notice in my servlet I create an instance of `personController` and add it to the `request`.  I then forward to the JSP containing the expression which resolves the expression and displays the value..

```
PersonController pc = new PersonController();
pc.getAllPeople().add(new Person("Joe"));
pc.getAllPeople().add(new Person("John"));
request.setAttribute("personController", pc);

String nextJSP = "/index.jsp";
RequestDispatcher dispatcher = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher(nextJSP);
dispatcher.forward(request,response);
```

---

### Using a JSP Tag

Another method of associating an instance of `personController` is to use the `<jsp:useBean/>` tag.

**UseBean Example JSP**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>

<jsp:useBean id="personController" class="org.test.PersonController" />

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
    <c:out value="${personController.allPeople[0].name }"/>
</body>
</html>
```

This will eliminate the nasty scriplets, but will require you to modify the `PersonController` class so that the default constructor will invoke the `populate()` method.

**org.test.PersonController.java**

```
public class PersonController {

    List<Person> allPeople = new ArrayList<Person>();

    public PersonController() {
        this.populate();
    }

    public void populate() {
        Person person = new Person("Jeff");
        person.setName("Jeff");
        allPeople.add(person);
    }
    /* Omitted Accessors */
}
```

Comment: @ThreaT It would be worth your time looking into servlets.  See the Gist I provided.  If you are looking to separate concerns using MVC, servlets are the first step.

Answer (score 5):

You need this -

```
<c:out value="${personController.allPeople[0].name}"/>
```

Comment: You simply updated your code and down-voted my response. Unfair!